# summary still shows NAs after using both na.omit and complete.cases

Tags: r, summary, na

I am a grad student using R and have been reading the other Stack Overflow answers regarding removing rows that contain NA from dataframes.  I have tried both na.omit and complete.cases.  When using both it shows that the rows with NA have been removed, but when I write summary(data.frame) it still includes the NAs.  Are the rows with NA actually removed or am I doing this wrong?

```
na.omit(Perios)
summary(Perios)

Perios[complete.cases(Perios),]
summary(Perios)
```

Comment: Figured it out!

Periosna=Perios[is.na(Perios$Periostitis)==FALSE,]
summary(Periosna)

Comment: If you feel that this might be helpful to future visitors, please post an answer with your solution, and accept it. Otherwise, please delete this question.

Comment: OP, what Dukeling said. Either post answer or delete please. How is `complete.cases` different to `Perios[!is.na(Perios$Periostitis),]` , I'm curious?

Comment: @smci It's the same if and only if there are no other columns containing `NA` values.

Answer (score 2):

1. The error is that you actually didn't assign the output from `na.omit` !

   `Perios <- na.omit(Perios)`
2. If you know which column the NAs occur in, then you can just do

   `Perios[!is.na(Perios$Periostitis),]`

or more generally:

```
Perios[!is.na(Perios$colA) & !is.na(Perios$colD) & ... ,]
```

Then as a general safety tip for R, throw in an na.fail to assert it worked:

```
na.fail(Perios)  # trust, but verify! Die Paranoia ist gesund.
```

Answer (score 1):

`is.na` is not the proper function.  You want `complete.cases` and you want `complete.cases` which is the equivalent of `function(x) apply(is.na(x), 1, all)` or `na.omit` to filter the data:

That is, you want all rows where there are no `NA` values.

```
< x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,NA), b=c(3,NA,NA))
> x
   a  b
1  1  3
2  2 NA
3 NA NA

> x[complete.cases(x),]
  a b
1 1 3

> na.omit(x)
  a b
1 1 3
```

Then this is assigned back to `x` to save the data.

`complete.cases` returns a vector, one element per row of the input data frame.  On the other hand, `is.na` returns a matrix.  This is not appropriate for returning complete cases, but can return all non-NA values as a vector:

```
> is.na(x)
         a     b
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE


> x[!is.na(x)]
[1] 1 2 3
```