# Why are NAs in newly created data.frame when using logical selection?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to get rid of `NAs` in an R data.frame. I was trying to create a new df that included only rows whose cluster was "texas" in this example.

```
> newdf <- df[df$cluster == "texas",]
> summary(newdf$cluster)
     texas    oklahoma            NA's 
      510           0             719
```

I had found [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079951/summary-still-shows-nas-after-using-both-na-omit-and-complete-cases) that address getting rid of NAs, but in this case, I was only selecting those whose "cluster" column is equal to "texas" -- how did an NAs come along for the ride?

Is there a better way of doing what I want?

Comment: You can do `df[which(df$cluster == "texas"),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MrFlick suggests above, `NA` values are handled in slightly (subtly?) different ways depending on how you index.

Test data:

```
dd <- data.frame(cluster=c("oklahoma","texas",NA))
```

1. **logical indexing**: a `TRUE` value in the index vector selects the corresponding value, `FALSE` drops it, and `NA` results in `NA`.

```
dd$cluster=="oklahoma"
## [1] TRUE FALSE NA
summary(dd[dd$cluster=="oklahoma",])
## oklahoma    texas     NA's 
##        1        0        1
```

In principle you could use `dd$cluster=="oklahoma" & !is.na(dd$cluster)` as your criterion - since `FALSE & NA` is `FALSE` - but that's rather awkward. (Since we have specified a single-column data frame, without saying `drop=FALSE`, the result gets simplified to a vector before being summarized.)

2. **subset**: although it is [sometimes deprecated for non-interactive use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset), `subset` has the convenient property that it drops values where the criterion evaluates to `NA`.  (Also, `subset` always returns a data frame even if the result is only one column wide.)

```
summary(subset(dd,cluster=="oklahoma"))
##      cluster 
##  oklahoma:1  
##  texas   :0
```

3. **which**:

`which()` only returns indices for `TRUE` values, not for `NA` values:

```
which(dd$cluster=="oklahoma")
## [1] 1
summary(dd[which(dd$cluster=="oklahoma"),])
## oklahoma    texas 
##        1        0
```